# How to delete synchronized files from FTP server using Batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I was wondering if someone knows how to do what I'm looking to do.

For my server, I download files from an FTP server daily at 5AM. My batch script is pretty simple, it connects to the FTP server, downloads the files, processes them locally, and then deletes the processed files from the local directory, but I am unable to figure out how to get the batch file to purge only the downloaded files from the server.

Here is the code I'm currently using (edited for privacy)

```
C:
cd "C:\targetfolder"

rem psftp -b download.cmd -i priv(second).ppk -P 2223 xxx@yyy.ca 
psftp -b download(second).cmd -i priv(second).ppk -P 2223 xxx@yyy.ca 

rem psftp -b download.cmd -i priv.ppk xxx@yyy.ca 
psftp -b download.cmd -i priv.ppk -P 2223 xxx@yyy.ca 

rename *.xxx *.xxx

del done*.*
```

So the script as it is successfully is run every morning and downloads my new files. Are there some line(s) of code I'm missing that will simply delete the downloaded files only?

I also want to mention that I cannot install any new software on my FTP server to manage the files, so it has to be processed in my batch code here.

Thank you in advance for any help you all may be able to provide!

EDIT1: Here is the script in the doanload.cmd

```
ls
cd target
ls
mget *
```

Comment: I've added it to the main question as EDIT1

Comment: So why don't you do `rm *`? Or do you want to do this transactionally? I.e. really delete only what was downloaded, in case new file is added during the download?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Quoting from my initial question: "I am unable to figure out how to get the batch file to **purge only the downloaded files from the server.**" Yes, I'm looking to just remove the downloaded files, as the server is updated with files regularly, I don't want to accidentally deletre a file that I haven't already downloaded.

Comment: I don't use WinSCP, it's not even installed on the server, so I fail to see how the other question relates, as that question's answer talks about using WinSCP. I have no desire to use WinSCP.

Comment: How it relates? *"psftp.exe get files from the server and delete"* - Sounds as exactly the same thing you are asking for! + The answer clearly says that psftp is not capable of this. WinSCP does not have to be installed on "server", you need it on the "client" only. And it does not even have to be installed. You can extract the portable package along with your script.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - The "Answer" to that question is the following: 

**"There's no easy way to do this with psftp. You would have to parse it's output to find files that were successfully downloaded**

This answer does not supply the code or any references as to how to "parse it's output to find the files that were downloaded". 

As well, in contrast you your last comment, "_The answer 'clearly' says that psftp is not capable of this_". This reply you linked me to states that psftp can do it, it's just "not easy". So which is it? Impossible? Or just difficult? Check your sources my friend.

Comment: Psftp cannot do it. Parsing its output is of course possible. But that's not a feature of psftp. + The fact that you are not happy with the answer does not change the fact that your question is duplicate.

Comment: Note that I wrote the answer, so believe me, that I know perfectly what it says. If you want our help, you should judge your words!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to @MartinPrikryl.

I added "rm *" to the end of my cmd file and it's working nicely, even though it doesn't differentiate from downloaded and non-downloaded files, it does what I need.

Thanks @MartinPrikryl!